# How could a relation of the form $t=-i\tau$ hold with both $t$ and $\tau$ being real?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time, path-integral, complex-numbers, wick-rotation

The physical time is a real quantity. But in quantum field theory, whenever we find oscillatory exponentials in time and we cannot literally take the limit $t\to \infty$, we make a change of variable, $t=-i\tau$ and take the limit $\tau\to \infty$ instead. But obviously, a relation of the form $t=-i\tau$ cannot hold with both $t$ and $\tau$ being real.

For example, consider the expression $$\langle q^\prime t^\prime|q,t\rangle=\sum\limits_n\phi_n(q^\prime)\phi_n^*(q)\exp[-\frac{i}{\hbar}E_n(t^\prime-t)].$$ We are interested in the limit $t\to -\infty$ and $t^\prime\to+\infty$. But since the phase factors are oscillatory in this limit, we do the followin trick. We make a change of variable $t=-i\tau$ so that the expression becomes $$\langle q^\prime, -i\tau^\prime|q,-i\tau\rangle=\sum\limits_n\phi_n(q^\prime)\phi_n^*(q)\exp[-\frac{1}{\hbar}E_n(\tau^\prime-\tau)].$$ After that we take the limit $\tau\to-\infty$ and $\tau^\prime\to +\infty$ to show
$$\langle q^\prime, t^\prime|q,t\rangle=\phi_0(q^\prime)\phi_0^*(q)\exp[-\frac{1}{\hbar}E_n(\tau^\prime-\tau)]$$ in this limit. How how can $\tau$ be real i $t$ is real and $t=-i\tau$ has to hold?

I have never found a satisfactory answer to this. Are we being mathematically sloppy here?

Comment: When people talk about "substituting $t = - i \tau$" they mean rotating an integration contour along the real axis of the complex plane to the imaginary axis -- just substituting directly wouldn't give meaningful results.

Comment: There is no contour integral in my example. Where did you find an integral over time here?

Comment: Where  was it stated that t is real? with $\tau$ being real, the t parameter is imaginary.

Comment: @mithusengupta123 The point is that there _should_ be a contour integral -- situations where one just "substitutes $t = - i \tau$" without a contour integral in sight are just sloppy, and don't really make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to use the examples you gave but I believe this will help as to when we use wick-rotation(i.e $t = -i\tau$)

In the path integral formulation we have learned that to compute the time-ordered Green's function we use $$ \langle0|T(\hat{q}(t_N)\hat{q}(t_{N-1})...\hat{q}(t_1)|0\rangle=\mathcal{N}\int{\mathcal{D}q\;q(t_N)q(t_{N-1})...q(t_1)exp(iS[q])}  $$

Now this integral looks ill-defined with a non vanishing exponential. To make things better we use $t=-i\tau$ with $\tau$ being real. This changes the metric to $$
ds^2=dt^2-d\vec{x}^2=-(d\tau^2+d\vec{x}^2)
$$

Now the action changes as $$
iS = -\int{d\tau\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dq}{d\tau}\right)^2+V(q)\right)}
$$
Which we define as $S_E=-iS$

Then the exponential has the form $$
\exp\left(-S_E\right)
$$
which makes integrals convergent.

Comment: t is time. Why should it be complex/imaginary?

Comment: It only makes sense when we integrate a value. Imagine an integral running from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. Now when we wick-rotate to $t=-i\tau$ we integrate again from$-\infty$ to $+\infty$ but in the imaginary axis(think of the complex plane). These 2 integrations are equivalent.